# Getting error when saving a file: Cannot access a closed Stream

Tags: c#, streamwriter, memorystream

I have a sitemap writer file which creates sitemap:

```
public class SitemapWriter : IDisposable
{
    public MemoryStream _outputStream;
    public StreamWriter _outputWriter;

    public SitemapWriter()
    {
        _outputStream = new MemoryStream();
        _outputWriter = new StreamWriter(_outputStream);
    }

    public MemoryStream SitemapStream => _outputStream;
    
    public void InitializeFile()
    {
        _outputWriter.WriteLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        _outputWriter.WriteLine("<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">");
    }

    public void FinalizeFile()
    {
        _outputWriter.WriteLine("</urlset>");
        FinalizeStream();
    }

    public void Append(string loc, string changeFreq)
    {
        _outputWriter.WriteLine("<url>");
        _outputWriter.WriteLine($"<loc>{loc}</loc>");
        _outputWriter.WriteLine($"<changefreq>{changeFreq}</changefreq>");
        _outputWriter.WriteLine("</url>");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _outputStream.Dispose();
        _outputWriter.Dispose();
    }
    
    private void FinalizeStream()
    {
        _outputWriter.Flush();
        _outputStream.Position = 0;
    }
}
```

And this is how I am using the above sitemap writer:

```
using (var writer = new SitemapWriter())
{
    writer.InitializeFile();
    writer.Append("url1", "hourly");
    writer.Append("url2", "hourly");
    writer.FinalizeFile();
    _s3Writer.SaveSitemap(writer.SitemapStream, "path", "filename.xml"); 
}
```

`_s3Writer` is an object which saves the file (i.e. `writer.SitemapStream`) to S3 bucket. When I debug the code it runs fine, but when I run it on the Test server, I get the following error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
>
> at System.IO.__Error.StreamIsClosed()
>
> at System.IO.MemoryStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>
> at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean
> flushEncoder)
>
> at System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
>
> at System.IO.TextWriter.Dispose()
>
> at MyProjectName.SitemapWriter.Dispose()
>
> in C:\MyProjectName\SitemapWriter.cs:line ...

I am not able to understand what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your outputwriter tries to flush the steam when disposed. However as you dispose the stream first, this fails. Try exchanging the lines in your Dispose method with each other. That being said: as your stream is a MemoryStream you don’t really need to dispose it as it has no Ressourcen it needs to free. So you could also just omit disposing the stream in this case.

Comment: Thanks, does it mean that when disposing the StreamWriter it calls `_outputStream.Flush();`?

Comment: Yes, but rather it’s calling Flush of the writer which is calling Write of the stream. When you try to dispose the writer, it tries to write out what’s left in its buffer.

Comment: This may also explain the behavior you observed that it doesn’t fail all the time. It could just be that when you debug it the buffer is somehow empty (and thus doesn’t need to be flushed), but when you run it the buffer may contain data which needs to be flushed.

Comment: Wrong dispose order.  Stream objects take ownership of their wrapped stream, just calling `_outputWriter.Dispose()` is enough to also dispose the memory stream.